# Cannot import my routes module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I try to import my routes module into the main app with `app.use(require(./routes))` I get `app.use() requires middleware functions`. How should I go about the `module.exports` function to make it work?

My routes:

```
var express = require('express'),
    auth = require('../middleware/auth.js'),
    user = require('../models/user.js'),
    formidable = require('formidable');

module.exports = (function () {
    app.post('/', function (req, res) {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
            user.create(fields.username, fields.email, fields.password);
        });
        res.render('./game/game.html', {});
    });

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('./index.html', {});
    });

    app.get('/game', function (req, res) {
        res.render('/views/index.html');
    });
})();
```

My main app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = require('express')(),
    cookieSession = require('cookie-session'),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    path = require('path'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    util = require('util'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    auth = require('./middleware/auth.js'),
    user = require('./models/user.js'),
    formidable = require('formidable');
    router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

//won't import routes
app.use(require('./routes'));

module.exports = router;

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Why do you require the IIFE in your routes?

Comment: Is `app` defined in your routes file?

Comment: [Using an `IIFE` is unnecessary in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/v6.2.0/api/globals.html#globals_global), plus in this case it actually breaks your code.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen Yes, sorry for ommitting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return app in your exports function

```
module.exports = function (express) {
  var app  = express.Router();
  app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        user.create(fields.username, fields.email, fields.password);
    });
    res.render('./game/game.html', {});
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('./index.html', {});
});

app.get('/game', function (req, res) {
    res.render('/views/index.html');
});

 return app

};
```

......

```
app.use(require('./routes')(express));
```

Comment: I get `cannot read property of undefined express.Router()`, even with express passed in as a parameter

Comment: in app.js, did you pass express into the route middleware? app.use(require('./routes')(express));

Comment: Indeed, I did, it's in the above comment.

Comment: make sure you are exporting a function. NOT an immediately executed one like (function() {})()

Answer (score 1):

Your routes need to be an instance of Express Router.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.headers);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now in your `app.js` you can use them as following:

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer on this question but it would be more complete if you showed how to incorporate the router into the main Express App.

Comment: Do I need to envelope the above snippet in `module.exports = function() {...`?

Comment: No, you're simply returning the `router`. No reason to wrap it in a function

Comment: @peteb error: `app.use() requires middleware functions`

Comment: `express.Router()` is an [express middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) and `router` is an instance of that so you can return it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your module should either mutate your router (`app`), or create its own router and export it.

## Solution 1

Module

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.post(...);
  app.get(...);
}
```

Main app

```
require("./routes")(app)
```

## Solution 2

Module

```
var app = express.Router();
app.post(...);
app.get(...);
module.exports = app;
```

Main app

```
app.use(require("./routes"))
```

Solution 2 is better in my opinion because it avoids mutation.

Comment: Why create a new express instance when you can just create a new Router Middleware using `express.Router()`. That would be the best approach.

Comment: First solution still complains about `app` being `undefined` inside the `module.exports` function, even though I pass it with `app.use(require('./routes'))(app);`

Comment: Solution 2 returns app.use() requires middlware ... Neither one works

Comment: @SvetanDimoff you are not passing app to your module: `app.use(require('./routes'))(app);` => `app.use(require('./routes')(app));` (notice the parens).

Comment: @SvetanDimoff as for solution 2, you probably copy-pasted my typo: it's `module.exports` not `module.export` (fixed now)